# Selecting parent element of class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $(".remove").click(function(){
        $("<need the right selector>").hide();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tag-collection">
    <div class="key">PULMONARY_EMBOLISM <span class="remove">✘</span></div>
</div>
```

I would ilke the above jQuery code to delete the entire div `tag-collection`. However, I will have many `tag-collection` divs on the page, and I want to make sure that when someone clicks the remove button that it only deletes the `tag-collection` div that the remove button was contained in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $(".remove").click(function(){
        $(this).parents('.tag-collection').hide();
    });
});
```

Emphasis on line #3.

**Edit:** As Kevin B states below, replacing `parents()` with `closest()` is probably better, since that will only select *one* ancestor.

Comment: By far the clearest answer. Using .closest() makes code unreadable.

Comment: However, if there are multiple elements with the class `tag-collection` that are ancestors of the clicked element, multiple elements will be removed. They serve two completely different purposes. I think `.closest()` would be the best fit here.

Comment: @Hidde how does "closest" make the code unreadable? If you're familiar with the jQuery API, you know that `.closest()` is the _best_ way to select a nearest ancestor. This sort of usage is very idiomatic.

Comment: It may be the best, but it still gives me shivers down my spine.

Comment: To be honest, I think `closest()` is actually better. Updating my answer to reflect this. (Sticking a call to `first()` after `parents()` would achieve the same, but that's not as clean).

Answer (score 4):

If you have a lot of them, this will bind fewer listeners, so it's more "efficient"/lighter-weight:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'span.remove', function() {
        $(this).closest('.tag-collection').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".remove").click(function(){
    $(this)  // points to clicked element
        .closest('.tag-collection') // jump to parent tag-collection
        .hide(); // hide that
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `closest` method, try this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".remove").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.tag-collection').remove();
    });
});
```